# Не срабатывает realloc с разыменованием указателя

Tags: c++, указатели, realloc

Есть два класса - родитель (Capture) и потомок (Camera). В родителе реализована одна общая функция, которая вызывает функцию, переопределённую у потомков:

```
bool Capture::WriteJPEG(const char * filename){
    unsigned char *frame;
    unsigned int size = GrabRGB(&frame);
    if( size){if(!jpge::compress_image_to_jpeg_file(filename, BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth, BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight, 3, frame, Compressor)) size = 0;}
    free(frame);
    return size!= 0;
}
```

В `GrabRGB` должна выделяться память под внешний массив (передаётся параметром), но этого не происходит:

```
unsigned int Camera::GrabRGB(unsigned char **out){
    WaitForSingleObject(M_Capture, INFINITE);
    capGrabFrame(CaptureWindow);
    unsigned int size = FrameSize;
    if( size){
        *out = (unsigned char *)realloc(*out, size);
        if(*out){memcpy(*out, FrameBuffer, size);}
        else{size = 0;}
    }
    else{free(out);}
    ReleaseMutex(M_Capture);
    return size;
}
```

Если убрать проверку `if(*out)`, то на `memcpy` будет ошибка сегментации. При этом я делал `cout`-ы на `FrameSize` и `FrameBuffer` - там всё в порядке, есть и размер, и полный буфер с кадром.

**Помогите пожалуйста понять и устранить причину не выделения памяти.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unsigned char *frame;
unsigned int size = GrabRGB(&frame);
```

Итак, `frame` ненинициализирована и содержит мусор.

```
*out = (unsigned char *)realloc(*out, size);
```

Что вы хотите реаллоцировать? В `*out` - мусор. Указатель фиг куда - естественно, что `realloc` не работает.

Comment: А как можно обезопасить функцию, если в неё передаётся не инициализированный указатель? Ведь не правильно будет проверить на `!= nullptr` и поставить его, тогда можно получить утечку памяти если указатель был не пустой... Или всегда делать `free` и `malloc`? но так вроде дольше отрабатывать будет... Как лучше?

Comment: Инициализировать все переменные - достаточно неплохое решение. Уже `unsigned char *frame = nullptr;` решает эту проблему.